# Form_for "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error in Admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have define Adminpanel namespace to separating admin area from index,Everything is good when i don't use Partial form,But when i trying to render my _form.html.erb in *new.html.erb* or *edit.html.erb* i getting error,But i cannot figure out why I'm getting this error message:

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

**Controller**

*path : controllers/adminpanel/posts_controller.erb*

```
module Adminpanel
    class PostsController<ApplicationController

        def index
            @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC')
            @post = Post.new
        end

        def show
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])
            @title = @post.title
            @content = @post.content
        end

        def new
            @post = Post.new
        end

        def create
            @post = Post.new(post_params)
            if @post.save
                flash[:success] = "متن مورد نظر ارسال شد."
                redirect_to adminpanel_post_path(@post)
            else
                render 'new'
            end
        end


        def update
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])
            if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
                flash[:success] = "متن مورد نظر ارسال شد."
                redirect_to  adminpanel_posts_path
            end
        end

        def destroy

        end

        private

        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title , :content)
        end
    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

*path : views/adminpanel/posts/_form.html.erb*

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container" style="text-align:right;direction:rtl;">
        <%= form_for([:adminpanel,@post],:method => :post) do |f| %>
                <% if @post.errors.any? %>
                    <div class="alert alert-dange" style="text-align:right;direction:rtl;"><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count,"خطا") %> رخ داده
                        <ul>
                            <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                                <li><%= msg %></li>
                        </ul>
                            <% end %>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
            <%= f.label "تیتر نوشته:" %>
            <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label "مطلب:" %>
            <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control' %><br />    
            <%= f.submit "ارسال پست", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Update

Error Full Trace:

```
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:432:in `form_for'
app/views/adminpanel/posts/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_adminpanel_posts_edit_html_erb___799339392__1038207668'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/lin0x/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/home/lin0x/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/lin0x/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/lin0x/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace along with your error?

Comment: Also, what action is this form for? Using `posts_controller.erb` is an odd way to name your view.

Comment: @AnthonyE,I update question with Full Trace of error,And sorry about incorrect file name I made mistake that's not posts_controller.erb,That's my _form.html.erb partial form file.

Comment: Thanks. This is the edit view, but where is your edit action? How is this view getting rendered? It seems as though `@post` may be nil.

Comment: Thank you Anthony,Isn't @post handle action according to my post controller? , I render _form.html.erb into edit.html.erb whit this <%= render 'form' %>

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/v2.1.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for , I talking about Resource-Oriented for_form in the link article, Is I am misunderstand about it?